# In a class called Digit, write a method called lastDigit that returns the last digit of an integer number

Tags: java

This is a homework question that I am stumped on. My professor suggests looking up the Math.abs() method.

I need to utilize a Scanner object in the main method to query for input from the user and then use the Scanner input as parameters to the specified methods.  In a class called Digit, write a method called lastDigit that returns the last digit of an integer number. For example, lastDigit(3572) should return 2.

Here is what I currently have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Digit {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int = scanIn.nextInt();


    }
    public int lastDigit(int number){
        int last =number%10;
        return last;

    }

}
```

Comment: SO helps with programming questions, *irrespective* of them being homework or not. Although this is not a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it is unclear what your question is.

Comment: I'm having trouble calling my lastDigit method to the scanner

Comment: Ah wait. Does Java return a negative number for a modulus on a negative input? That may clarify the hint your professor gave you.

Comment: @DanielVassallo - If you are confused about this for two weeks then I am pretty sure that you have not been reading your books or your professor teaches you almost nothing. I strongly suspect the former. What is the problem you have in understanding this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Java preserves sign when handling the modulo. `105 % 10 == 5` while `-105 % 5 == -5`. You need to get rid of the minus sign for negative numbers, and `Math.abs` allows you to do precisely that: `return Math.abs(last);` should work.

For a slightly more verbose solution, you could check if the solution would be negative, and multiply by `-1` if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks! got it. heres my updated code: import java.util.Scanner;

public class Digit {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);
  
  System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
  int a= scanIn.nextInt();
  System.out.print(lastDigit(a));
  
  
  
 }
 public static int lastDigit(int a){
  int last =a%10;
  return Math.abs(last);
  
 }

}